# Adding a new column vs adding more rows system efficiency

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table that contains postal codes with their associated salesperson. We are adding a modification were in the end there will be multiple salespersons associated with each postal code. Is it best practice to just add a new column for the new salesperson or to add more rows?

There are roughly 1.5 million postal codes in the table.

Comment: Absolutely NO!!! You would not want to add another column for the salesperson. This sounds like you may already have some serious normalization issues. You would need three tables for this type of thing. PostalCodes, SalesPerson and SalesPersonPostalCodes.

Comment: I agree but thank you for the reassurance. It is a table that was created long before everyone who works here now.

Comment: It may not be too late to fix this. I am guessing you already have duplicate PostalCodes and/or sales people in this table. I feel your pain. It is never easy to unravel horrible designs left for us to discover from the people who already ran away screaming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither.

Adding a new column for a new salesperson is a non-starter.  You'd have to keep adding columns arbitrarily in order to add new salespersons.  This is just a bad idea in every way.

Adding new rows changes the meaning of the data in the table.  The table holds postal codes and information regarding those entities.  It shouldn't be responsible for anything more than that.

What you're describing is a many-to-many relationship.  This would be accomplished by way of a linking table between the two entities.  Something as simple as this:

```
PostalCode
---------------
ID
Code
etc.

Salesperson
---------------
ID
Name
etc.

SalespersonPostalCode
---------------
ID
SalesPersonID
PostalCodeID
```

Each row in `PostalCode` represents a postal code.  Each row in `Salesperson` represents a salesperson.  And each row in the linking table represents a relationship between the two.  You'd add as many relationships as you want.  But don't arbitrarily add new domain entity records when what you want is to add more relationships between them.